# Running a test on Python script - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have a simple file program (removed code from functions since its irrelevant for the problem):

```
import random
import sys


def poziom(level):
    *does something and returns something*

def gra(chance):
    *does something and returns something*


def save(name):
    *does something and returns something*


while True:
    *does something in loop, executing other functions above*
```

I'm trying to run a simple unit test against one of its functions:

```
import unittest

from my_game import save
from my_game import gra
from my_game import poziom




class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_list_int(self):
        """
        Test that it can sum a list of integers
        """
        check = "Test string"
        result = poziom(check)
        self.assertEqual(result, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, this test instead of running a poziom() function, runs through entire file, also executing the code behind the While True statement.
Do I do something wrong? Is it possible in such case to write a test that checks ONLY one function and value returned by it?

Comment: If you put the `while True:` in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, does that fix it? Otherwise, just importing that file will execute the contents of that loop.

Answer (score 4):

> However, this test instead of running a poziom() function, runs through entire file, also executing the code behind the While True statement. Do I do something wrong?

This is how `import` works. It executes the code in the file that you import. To solve the problem put the while loop in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` just like you do in your test file.

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. I did like you said: 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        unittest.main()

But executing tests still throws me to the while true loop inside the main file.

Comment: @MikaelDiak Which file did you edit? `unittest.main()` is in the test file, but `while True` is in the file with the functions.